# Superpowered AdvancedAudioPlayer. How to wait for caching?

Tags: superpowered

I am using superpowered sdk for playing audio files. And I need to wait while SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer caching a file. Here is pseudocode that i tried:

```
void loading (shared_ptr<SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer> player, string path)
{
    player->open(path.c_str());
    player->cachePosition(0, 0);
}

int main ()
{
    string filePath = "/path/file.wav";

    shared_ptr<SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer> player;
    player = make_shared<SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer>(nullptr, nullptr, 44100, 10, 2, 0);
    thread Loading(loading, player, filePath);
    char *tmp = (char*)&player->waitingForBuffering;
    Loading.join();
    while (*tmp) {usleep(10000);}

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work for me. waitingForBuffering all times true.
What is the valid way to wait?

Comment: You only check waiting for buffering one time. Keep checking it in the while loop.

Comment: I don't know the superpowered player, but I would expect that it has a callback function to say when it has buffered, rather than using a busy loop.